# There is no position at Row #

Tags: vb.net

I have a .CSV that contains duplicates. As I fill my dataTable I want to filter out the duplicates and add certain cells up.

My columns:

```
  With table.Columns
            .Add(currentRow(0).ToString) '0
            .Add(currentRow(3).ToString) '3
            .Add(currentRow(5).ToString) '5
            .Add(currentRow(6).ToString) '6
            .Add(currentRow(8).ToString) '8
        End With
```

My header:

> `table.Rows.Add(table.Columns(0).ToString, table.Columns(1).ToString, table.Columns(2).ToString, table.Columns(3).ToString, table.Columns(4).ToString)`

And when I proceed to check currentRows to whats already on my table I get an error saying "There is no row at position #"

It will only work if I have this piece of code in it that defines my header but with improper formatting.

```
 With table.Rows
                .Add(currentRow(0).ToString) '0
                .Add(currentRow(3).ToString) '3
                .Add(currentRow(5).ToString) '5
                .Add(currentRow(6).ToString) '6
                .Add(currentRow(8).ToString) '8
            End With
```

This is my If statement where I compare an element of currentRow to the first column and rows.

```
 If currentRow(0).ToString Is table.Rows(someVal).Item(0) Then
```

In testing I can see the properly formatted header but my If Statement won't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Is` keyword determines if two object references refer to the same object, but do not compare the values of objects. Use `=` instead

```
If currentRow(0).ToString = table.Rows(someVal).Item(0) Then
```

---

Is a DataTable the right object for filtering out duplicates? Consider creating a class that represents your data in an appropriate way. If you override the `Equals` method in your class, getting distinct objects is then done easily with LINQ.

```
Dim list = New List(Of MyClass)

' Add objects
list.Add(New MyClass(...))
list.Add(New MyClass(...))
...

'Get unique objects
Dim unique = list.Distinct()
For Each obj As MyClass In unique
    ' process obj
Next
```

Comment: Having changed the if statement didn't help. I'm just using a datatable as a middle man as I sort out what I'm reading in from a file. every input that gets put is checked against the ones before it, if any. Any duplicates found are then combined.

It seems that anytime I try to access a row from the datatable I'm told the row doesn't exist, but when I write the datatable to a file  I can easily see the output.

Comment: Why are you adding rows as columns in your first code snippet? Are you mixing up rows and columns?

Comment: currentRow() is a string array grabbed from a textFieldParser. I'm merely creating the columns(my width of the table) by picking the elements from my currentRow.

Comment: I don't know what's going on. Analyze the code by using the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the failing line. The execution will stop before the line is executed. You can tehn see the value of each variable and parameter, check the number of rows and columns etc.